# Will it be helpful to break a long html into sections and load them with PHP or AJAX

Tags: html, ajax

I have written a single-page style webpage. There are 7-8 sections inside it, and each section has pretty much content. Will it be helpful or necessary to split those sections into separate PHP or HTML files and load them using AJAX or PHP?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be good choice to use AJAX for loading multiple sections, as the rendering of the content will be split up according to sections, which will result into faster loading and rendering.

Using AJAX you should load only the required section only when it is going to be used, consider the current usage of the section while loading.

In case of loading all of the content at once the loading and rendering will take more time, and the unnecessary section at the moment will cause delay in the part that is necessary.

Comment: But in my case, all sections are necessary. Will it still be helpful to load them as separate files? I was initially thinking it might be easier to edit if the sections are loaded in separate files - as in this way, I don't need to open a huge html file to edit one of the sections. And currently I'm using PHP require to load the section files. Any suggestions or ideas? Thanks.

Comment: you can load all of the section one by one, make AJAX calls or PHP require (I am not much familiar with PHP) this way it will reduce the load on DOM, instead of loading the bulk of stuff at once.